# Flex background not changed after changing theme

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

So I am pretty new to flex. I am developing an AIR application and I want to change my project theme to one of the additional included themes that is packaged with Flash Builder 4. So, I went to the Project Theme and changed it and it looks like it is supposed to in the Design View. When I run the application, the components (eg: a button) themselves look like it is supposed to, but the application's background is just white instead of the displayed color in the design view. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Does hitting the "refresh" button on the design tab solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to [update the default background color](http://www.internaldrive.com/2009/02/13/removing-the-default-flex-blue-and-other-style-tips/) in your compiler arguments.